# How to search firestore collections with multiple search keys using startAt() and endAt methods

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say we have a collection of "people" inside people collection we have person objects of

```java
public class Person{
    public String personId;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
}
```

I want to search persons by using firstName and lastName in the same time with startAt and endAt methods like below

```java
Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                        .collection("people").orderBy("firstName",
                                Query.Direction.ASCENDING).
                                orderBy("lastName", Query.Direction.ASCENDING).startAt(key).endAt(key + "\uf8ff");

                FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Person> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Person>()
                        .setQuery(query, Person.class)
                        .build();
```

but I can only use either firstName or lastName how can I use both at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that startAt and endAt are the right things for you.  Those are used for pagination, and it doesn't look like that's what you're trying to do here.  If you just want to filter all people by some common first and last time, just do a normal query with where clauses to filter those names and order them as needed:

```java
Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    .collection("people")
    .whereEqualTo("lastName", yourLastName)
    .whereEqualTo("firstName", yourFirstName)
    .orderBy("lastName")
    .orderBy("firstName")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this answer is not what I want, what I want is when I search it searches either firstName or lastName here the logic is AND not OR and I don't want equalTo I want %LIKE% (like what we have in SQL)

Comment: Firestore does not have LIKE queries.